# Nivo Slider Display Problem in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nivo-slider

I am using Nivo Slider, and am experiencing the "stacking" problem -- with all of the images initially loading on top of each other. I have tried the workaround for this problem described at  http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/ but this results in the images not displaying at all in IE. I have also tried the workaround of including "display:none" in the style tag but this has the same effect in IE. You can see the code, currently without the workaround, at http://www.rooftopdrinker.com. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something about IE's box model confuses the Nivo code.

Adding this CSS rule seems to fix it:

```
#slider { height: 355px; }
```

Comment: Good, This solves the problem on IE 11. The same rule can be applied for [carouFredSel](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/caroufredsel/) (from Dev7Studios as well) in case of problems, just tested.